# How can I uninstall VMware 8 Workstation from Ubuntu Studio 12.04.1 LTS?

Tags: uninstall, vmware

I have tried a few things already but I still can't seem to uninstall it. The last thing I tried was this code:

```
vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-workstation
```

and that didn't work for me. I even tried it as root and got this message:

```
vmware-installer: command not found.
```

If anyone has other ideas please let me know I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you try sudo vmware-installer -u  package-name

Answer (score 0):

You have to locate the command :

```
which vmware-installer
```

The default must be under `/usr/lib` so do the following(replace your path to command if its changed in your machine).

```
sudo /usr/lib/vmware-installer -u PRODUCT
```

For a list of which products are installed, you may run:

```
/usr/lib/vmware-installer -l
```

**Another way is to remove manually**

Follow this [**link**](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=38) to do it so.